# Netlify redirect to www not working on gatsby site

Tags: redirect, gatsby, netlify

I'm trying to redirect all urls without www to www, i have the following rules in my netlify.toml file

```
[[redirects]]
  from = "/"
  to = "/es"
  status = 302
  force = false
  conditions = {Country = ["es"], Language = ["es","EU-es"]}

[[redirects]]
  from = "https://example.com/*"
  to = "https://www.example.com/:splat"
  status = 301
  force = true
```

The first rule works, but the second rule which is general rule to redirect all requests without www to www is not working. I'm using gatsby v1 with typescript.

Comment: What is happening ? Did you clear caches of the browser ?

Comment: Netlify offers to do this when you configure your domain settings, without even the use of `_redirects`. It's unclear to me why you would want to use (paid) lambda functions to do this instead.

Answer (score 0):

Netlify does this redirect automatically if you set your site's primary custom domain to `www.example.com` and you have a valid SSL certificate for the hostname.  In case `example.com` and `www.example.com` are secondary hostnames (called domain aliases:  https://www.netlify.com/docs/custom-domains/#domain-aliases) then you would likely want/need this redirect.

Usually people put those kinds of redirects *above* the other ones like your 302/language redirect so that it happens first, but that is probably not the (only) problem with it if it is not working.

Note: That will ONLY catch requests to literally https://example.com(/*) and not requests to `http://example.com` in case you do not have your site forcing ssl (which should never be the case - Netlify tries to force automatically for all sites).

If you're finding that not to work and you've met the prerequisites:
- netlify site configured with those hostnames
- SSL certificate on the netlify site with support for those hostnames
...then it is possible we either didn't process it correctly and so it is not in place, or something else in the system is wrong and you should contact [Netlify's helpdesk](https://www.netlify.com/support) for a hand in investigating, since the redirects that were processed are not shown anywhere and trying to understand what was processed by trial and error is not a very awesome process :)